# How do I safely delete a remote git branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

To delete a local branch in git I use `git branch -d`, but how do I safely remove a remote branch?

I would like to delete it **only when the remote branch is merged to my current branch**.

Comment: Why not just be sure and merge your upstream branch with your local branch before deleting it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is partly covered here: [How can I know in git if a branch has been already merged into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-in-git-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master)

While that post copes with local branches, you could find remote branches that are merged or not using

- `git branch -r --merged` to detect all remote branches that are already merged into the current
- `git branch -r --unmerged` to do the opposite
- `git branch -r --no-merged` is correct for the new version of `Git` and I'm not sure whether `git branch -r --unmerged` is applicable for old `git`.

Once you found that a specific remote branch is already merged (i.e. it appears when typing `git branch -r --merged`), you could delete it as [Michael Krelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95382/michael-krelin-hacker) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093653/520162) using

```
git push <remote> :<remotebranchname>
```

See also the documentation of [`git branch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-branch) for the `--merged` and `--unmerged` flags.

Comment: thanks for proposing to remove the downvote, I don't think 2 points are worth the hassle, though. As a bonus you get an upvote ;)

Comment: Have somebody a way to automate this process (list remote merged branches and delete them)?

Comment: In git 1.8 (dunno about previous versions) it's `--no-merged` instead of `--unmerged`.

Comment: `git log -S '--unmerged' -p .` in Git's Documentation directory shows only entries about `git ls-files --unmerged`, but I can't find any trace of `git branch --unmerged` in current or past Git.

Answer (score 5):

Just to point out that for unmerged branches it seems the option now is --no-merged as explained on http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch