# Git: easy (feature-)branch cleanup

Tags: git

Our development process involves using git feature branches and code reviews done through github. It's working pretty well for us. The one downside is that we're doing cleanup manually.

I'm familiar with git-unmerged (http://mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2009/07/02/finding-unmerged-commits-with-git-unmerged) and the built-in git cherry to find branches with unmerged changes.

I'm wondering if anyone has a tool that does the opposite of them. e.g. list branches that have no unmerged changes and are, thus, safe to delete. Or maybe an option on push that won't delete if unmerged changes are found? (didn't see one in the docs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I know in git if a branch has been already merged into master?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-in-git-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master)

Comment: found my question elsewhere on SO already, doh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the --no-merged argument to git branch:

```
git branch --no-merged <commit>
```

If < commit > is omitted, HEAD is assumed.

Comment: I was unaware of the --merged and --no-merged options. The merged one is actually what I was looking for, but this is still very useful.

Comment: This is only showing me local branches. How can I run this for a remote like github?  Answer: `git branch -r --merged`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the git-cherry command for this - http://blog.sdqali.in/2012/04/finding-un-merged-commits-with-git.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, git-unmerged has a --prune option which does what I want

```
git-unmerged --prune
```