# git cleanup old branches

Tags: git, git-bash

I'd like to create a git command that will delete any branches that have all commits included in the current branch e.g.

```
$ git branch
  groups
* master

$ git cleanup-branches
deleted groups # all commits are included in master

$ git branch
* master
```

How would I go about creating this?

Comment: Finding the branches is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-in-git-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can leverage `git branch -d` here, as it won't delete any branch not yet merged into your current branch:

```
git config --global alias.cleanup-branches \
'!git branch | grep -v "\*" | awk "{ print $1 }" | xargs git branch -d'
```

Just tried this locally and it worked, although it is a little terrifying to watch it work.

Comment: ha! yeah, that's one way to do it, try and delete everything! Having said that it does seem like a reliable way to do it.

Comment: To avoid negative emotions completely do a dry run first (add `--dry-run` to the last git command). It will just list what would be deleted