# How to know if latest commit to master has been pushed to the remote?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, commit

I have merged a branch in to master and now I can see that in my `git log`

Some time has passed and now I want to know whether I previously also pushed master (with that commit) to the remote.  How can I tell if it has been pushed?

I can think of a few workaround such as recloning the repository elsewhere, or resetting and checking and then re-merging but I feel that there's probably a somewhat simpler answer.

fyi this is different from [How can I know in git if a branch has been already merged into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-in-git-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master) as I know it has been merged, just don't know about the remote push.

Comment: Have you tried : git status

Comment: That would show me whether or not it's been added to the staging area and also whether or not it's been staged into the index.  Where would it show whether that's actually been pushed to the remote?

Comment: If it is automerged, then it says your branch is ahead by XXX commits. By that information, it can be judged that the remote branch is lagging by some commits which local repo has.

Comment: I also have this question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Do

```
> git status
```

If the output is

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Then you have pushed the current commit.

If the output instead begins with

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Then you have a local commit that has not yet been pushed. You see this because the remote branch, `origin/master`, points to the commit that was last pushed to origin. However, your branch is `ahead of 'origin/master'`, meaning that you have a local commit that has been created after the last pushed commit.

If the commit you are interested in is not the latest, then you can do

```
> git log --decorate --oneline
```

to find out if the commit in question is before or after the commit pointed to by `origin/master`.
If the commit is after (higher up in the log than) `origin/master`, then it has not been pushed.

Comment: It doesn't always work. E.g. it works for me in random github repository. However when I use `git status` in our local project, the line simply absent, i.e. after `On branch master` immediately follows the `Untracked files` line.

Comment: @Hi-Angel is this a completely local project that has not been pushed to a remote? That is, a project with no corresponding remote repository? In such a project `git status` would never mention any `origin`.

Comment: No, I mean "local" in the sense it's not a public project. It does have a "remote origin".

Comment: So, occasionally, I found the answer on IRC: I was missing the `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master master` command. When using `git clone`, git usually sets it automatically, but in my case it was locally created code and then added "origin", so apparently I had to call it manually. Now I see the difference with remote too.

Comment: This is not true if you have never pushed your branch to a remote: it will still say `nothing to commit, working directory clean`.

Comment: @ConnorLow but that is not what the question was about. OP was trying to remember if he "previously also pushed master", this confusion would hardly occur if he _never_ pushed to a remote at all.

Answer (score 25):

If you have made multiple commits and not sure which one of them have been pushed to remote, try this:

```
git log origin/<remote-branch>..<local-branch>
```

Example:

```
git log origin/master..master
```

This would list out all commits in your local branch that have not been pushed to the remote branch mentioned.

Comment: I found this more reliable that the selected answer. For some reason on my system, ```git status``` does not always report if local branch is ahead.

Answer (score 21):

Programmatically (for example, in a script):

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor HEAD @{u}
```

You may also want to check if your local directory is clean, e.g. there are no uncommitted file changes:

```
test -z "$(git status --porcelain)"
```

Comment: Good one – perfect for my use (+1) with a minor adjustment: Note that if you have no remote named "upstream", `@{u}` will fail. In such a case, instead use `git rev-parse refs/remotes/<remote-name>/<remote-branch>` – e.g. `git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master` if your remote is named "origin" and you want to check its "master" branch.

Comment: Ad your last example - how is that gonna make your script exit? You're making the exit 1 command in a subshell. Instead, you can use `{}` grouping, which uses current shell: `test your_condition || { echo "ERROR: you have local changes"; exit 1; }` -- the whitespace and semicolons inside the `{}` are significant.

Comment: @dwelle I'm always using `-euET` flags of bash.

Comment: The comparison of `@{u}` and `HEAD` only tells you if your HEAD happens to be the same as the HEAD at origin.  What if origin's HEAD is now 10 commits ahead of your HEAD?  Then your test would fail, even though your HEAD has been pushed already.

Comment: @tanager I think you're right. I changed the code the check if the commit is ancestor instead of equality. Thanks for the remark!

Comment: I think you need to swap your arguments around. `--is-ancestor A B` returns 0 (success) if a is an ancestor of B. This will pretty much always be true when A is the upstream branch and B is your local branch.

Comment: @BrechtMachiels I think you're right, thanks for writing! Edited the answer.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `git log --graph --all --decorate`, it will show where each ref is located (HEAD, master, origin/master etc.)

Comment: This is my favorite answer because it gives the information EXPLICITLY: "commit XYZ (origin/master)". The commands in the other answers merely imply it by showing no information about unpushed commits. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you run this:

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
Fetching upstream
```

This will fetch the latest data from all remotes.

Then you run:

```
$ git branch -v
  master       ef762af [ahead 3] added attach methods
* testing      4634e21 added -p flag
  upstream     1234567 [ahead 1, behind 7] updated README.md
```

This will show which branches you're ahead or behind on.

I posted this because none of the other answers mention fetching the remote data, that step is crucial.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. `git branch -r --contains <sha1>`

For a commit in my repository I can see it exists on the remote develop branch

```
git branch  -r --contains 7914e54ea7e30c7f446e791df66bd3a5805c978a
origin/develop
```