# How to do Git Log see only merges to master branch?

Tags: git

In my work process I need to provide a list of files to my server admin.
The list comes from the merge of my working branch (Branch A) into Master branch.

So I merge branch A into branch Master and then deploy Master.

Right now the best I could do with `git log` is the following but this list contains other commit as well ( not only the merge I'm looking for ):
`git log -m --name-only --author=[NAME]`

So basically I need to retrieve the files list for the merge of `Branch A` into `Master Branch`

Is it possible with cli command ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Narrow it down using `git log --merges --author` to figure out the commit you want and then try

```
git diff --name-only ${MERGE_SHA}^1..${MERGE_SHA}
```

Answer (score 36):

I find it useful to narrow the path to first parent in order to ignore "update branch" merges.

Looks like this for me:

`git log r2.8.7-2018-09-04..HEAD --merges --first-parent`

Comment: What is "r2.8.7-2018-09-04" in this context?

Comment: I'd assume it's a `tag` or a `branch` of the latest release.

Answer (score 5):

I have the following alias configured in git for this purpose:

```
alias.merges=log --oneline --decorate --color=auto --merges --first-parent
```

This is useful to see all previous merges to the branches (wtih release tags) useful when updating deployment terraform configs:

```
$ git merges -5
ad2b1a1 (HEAD -> master, tag: 22.09.00003, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'feature/E' into 'master'
80ca202 (tag: 22.09.00002) Merge branch 'feature/D' into 'master'
8d693c3 (tag: 22.09.00001) Merge branch 'feature/C' into 'master'
09604e4 (tag: 22.09.00000) Merge branch 'feature/B' into 'master'
70285a5 (tag: 22.08.00009) Merge branch 'feature/A' into 'master'
```

Like previous answers state you can then see difference between releases like:

```
$ git diff 22.09.00000..22.09.00002
```