# Finding developers branches after they had been merged into master

Tags: git

Problem - find all developers branches after they had been merged into master. Extension - do this for all revisions between tags X and Y.

```
X-----A----B---C---D---E----Y
       \              /
        F------G-----H
```

Using git CLI, how to find pairs (A,F) and (E,H) ?

Comment: Typically you'd make use of tags.

Comment: Do you use merge commits? If so this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986534/how-to-do-git-log-see-only-merges-to-master-branch

Answer (score 0):

(If by "branches" you mean *branch names*, you can't: that information is gone.)

Assuming you mean to find the *commits*, it's easy to find `E` and hence also `D` and `H`: `git rev-list --min-parents=2 <endpoint>` enumerates commits with two or more parents.  `--min-parents=2` can be spelled `--merges`.  Given commit `E`, you can look at its parents, or have `git rev-list` spit out the parent hashes on the same line has the merge's hash, giving you the hash IDs of `D` and `H`.

Finding `A` and `F` is more difficult, but potentially also wrong:

```
...--o--x--...--x----...----M--o
         \       \         /
          *--...--*--...--o
```

Both starred commits lead back into the first-parent-leg ancestry of `M`, so *both* are potential points of interest.

I'm not sure offhand whether it is possible to get `git rev-list` to identify the two starred commits here.  Note that in this sort of graph, all but one of these is a merge, but we can also have:

```
...--o--x----...----W--...--M--o
         \         /       /
          *--...--*--...--o
```

where `W` is also a merge, this time on the first-parent line from `M`, that brings in commits from the second-parent line across the bottom.

All the merges will come out of a `rev-list` whose output is limited to `--merges`.  Add `--first-parent` to avoid traversing the second leg.

You can use `git rev-list --parents` to generate the data needed to build the graph, then write your own graph-handling algorithms, to select anything you like.  Note that `git rev-list` can also be used with `--ancestry-path` and the `X..Y` syntax to enumerate those commits that:

1. are ancestors of Y (including Y itself); but
2. are not ancestors of X (thus excluding X itself); and
3. have X as an ancestor, i.e., are descendants of X

The normal `X..Y` gives you commits that satisfy conditions one and two only, which means that in a graph like this:

```
          o--o   <-- X
         /    \
...--o--o--*---*--*   <-- Y
```

you get all the starred commits.  Adding `--ancestry-path` knocks out the leftmost starred commit since it's not a descendant of commit `X` (though `git rev-list` actually determines this not by testing "is the commit descendant of X" but rather "is X an ancestor of the commit"—the arcs connecting the nodes in the DAG all point backwards, so is-ancestor is an easy test, while is-descendant is hard).