# Your configuration specifies to merge with the <branch name> from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.?

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket, tortoisegit, pull

I am getting this error for pull:

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref
>   'refs/heads/feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch' from the remote, but no
>   such ref was fetched.

This error is not coming for any other branch.
The special thing about this branch is that it is created from the previous commit of another branch.

My config file looks like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = <url here>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "new-develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/new-develop
[branch "feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch
```

Comment: Can you share the command you're using to do the merge?

Comment: This problem can happen when the remote branch has been deleted. Double check if it's really there.

Comment: Future readers: If you know the remote branch exists, check if you are ignoring case or not.  I had setup a local branch to track a remote branch, but typed the remote's name in all lower case letters.  Just had to reconfigure local to track origin/BranchName instead of origin/branchname

Comment: I just had this error and the problem was much simpler than the answers below, I'd lost my VPN connection. So this is also the error you get if git can't access the remote origin server.

Comment: With solutions involving pruning the local branches to match the remote, first make sure you are not actually *on* the deleted branch locally, and especially that you don't have uncommitted changes on that branch.

Comment: There are excellent answers provided, so no need to add any new answers. But my 2 cents, when i get this message it means that the origin branch has been deleted, usually because it was deleted when it was merged into another branch. This is a common practice to keep the origin repo free of clutter from old branches.

Comment: This just happened to me, Github deleted my branch on merge (this merge was done using the website, while I usually use the gh command-line program), it is as @BennyNeugebauer points out, make sure the branch is not deleted on remote.

Comment: As @angryITguy mentioned this is likely to be because the branch was deleted (to keep things tidy) when it was merged into master. For example gitlab encourages this with a checkbox on the merge page. You can see whether the branch was merged at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master. So using git branch --merged master. If it has indeed been merged you are fine; clear the 'error' message with git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master

Answer (score 356, accepted):

#### What this means

Your upstream—the remote you call `origin`—no longer has, or maybe never had (it's impossible to tell from this information alone) a branch named `feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch`.  There's one particularly common reason for that: someone (probably not you, or you'd remember) deleted the branch in that other Git repository.

#### What to do

This depends on what you *want*.  See the discussion section below.  You can:

- create or re-create the branch on the remote, or
- delete your local branch, or
- anything else you can think of.

#### Discussion

You must be running `git pull` (if you were running `git merge` you would get a different error message or no error message at all).

When you run `git fetch`, your Git contacts another Git, based on the `url` line under the `[remote "origin"]` section of your configuration.  That Git runs a command (`upload-pack`) that, among other things, sends *your* Git a list of all branches.  You can use `git ls-remote` to see how this works (try it, it is educational).  Here is a snippet of what I get when running this on a Git repository for `git` itself:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
From [url]
bbc61680168542cf6fd3ae637bde395c73b76f0f    HEAD
60115f54bda3a127ed3cc8ffc6ab6c771cbceb1b    refs/heads/maint
bbc61680168542cf6fd3ae637bde395c73b76f0f    refs/heads/master
5ace31314f460db9aef2f1e2e1bd58016b1541f1    refs/heads/next
9e085c5399f8c1883cc8cdf175b107a4959d8fa6    refs/heads/pu
dd9985bd6dca5602cb461c4b4987466fa2f31638    refs/heads/todo
[snip]
```

The `refs/heads/` entries list all of the branches that exist on the remote,<sup>1</sup> along with the corresponding commit IDs (for `refs/tags/` entries the IDs may point to tag objects rather than commits).

Your Git takes each of these branch names and *changes* it according to the `fetch` line(s) in that same `remote` section.  In this case, your Git replaces `refs/heads/master` with `refs/remotes/origin/master`, for instance.  Your Git does this with every branch name that comes across.

It also records the original names in the special file `FETCH_HEAD` (you can see this file if you peek into your own `.git` directory).  This file saves the fetched names and IDs.

The `git pull` command is meant as a convenience short-cut: it runs `git fetch` on the appropriate remote, and then `git merge` (or, if so instructed, `git rebase`) with whatever arguments are needed to merge (or rebase) as directed by the `[branch ...]` section.  In this case, your `[branch "feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch"]` section says to fetch from `origin`, then merge with whatever ID was found under the name `refs/heads/feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch`.

Since nothing was found under that name, `git pull` complains and stops.

If you run this as two separate steps, `git fetch` and then `git merge` (or `git rebase`), your Git would look at your cached `remotes/origin/` remote-tracking branches to see what to merge with or rebase onto.  If there *was* such a branch at one time, you may still have the remote-tracking branch.  In this case, you would not get an error message.  If there was never such a branch, or if you have run `git fetch` with `--prune` (which removes dead remote-tracking branches), so that you have no corresponding remote-tracking branch, you would get a complaint, but it would refer to `origin/feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch` instead.

**In either case**, we can conclude that `feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch` does not exist now on the remote named `origin`.

It probably did exist at one time, and you probably created your local branch from the remote-tracking branch.  If so, you probably still have the remote-tracking branch.  You might investigate to see who removed the branch from the remote, and why, or you might just push something to re-create it, or delete your remote-tracking branch and/or your local branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, all that it is going to *admit* to, at least.  But unless they have specifically hidden some refs, the list includes everything.

**Edit, Jul 2020:** There's a new fetch protocol that can avoid listing *everything*, and only list names that your Git says it's looking for.  This can help with repositories that have huge numbers of branches and/or tags.  However, if your Git is interested in all possible names, you'll still get all the names here.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the git pull command actually does. I was able to fix my issue by running git fetch and then merge.

Comment: To remove non-existent remote branch references in your local repository, use `git remote prune origin`

Comment: @Ben-Uri: yes, or, run `git fetch --prune origin`, or set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your configuration (all three are intended to do the same thing, although in a few versions of Git some of these were not quite reliable).

Comment: You'd need to `git checkout <your remote branch>` and all be good (in some cases).

Comment: Wow... So weird. This only happens to me when connecting to BitBucket.  :(

Comment: @WillStrohl: to see what branches the Git at Bitbucket actually has, use `git ls-remote <name-of-bitbucket-remote>`. Your current branch has, as its upstream, a branch name that does not exist in that Git at Bitbucket. How you got there, and what to do about it, is in the answer above.

Comment: The problem for me was that I deleted a development branch on Github without ever merging it (I abandoned the change). I got the same error message as the original poster. The solution for me was to delete my _local_ `master` branch and re-create it.

Comment: @JonathanBenn: you can use `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` to switch the upstream setting for your local `master`.  Delete-and-recreate has that as a side effect (assuming you use the DWIM-style `git checkout master` to create it), with an additional side effect of forcing your `master` to match your `origin/master`.

Comment: @torek thanks, my Git-fu was not up to the task on this one. I'll keep in mind your recommendation for next time. I must have created a new local branch based on the deleted remote one, and then renamed my local branch to `master`.

Comment: argh! I ran into this.  A github project renamed the master branch main!

Comment: Merging my staging to main branch - pull request completion deleted my branch. Couldn't find staging later on. Thanks for explaining the options.

Comment: @sbsatter: pull requests are outside of Git (Git has no pull requests). GitHub's PR protocol allows you to semi-automatically delete the GitHub branch once the PR is merged. Other hosting sites may have similar features.

Answer (score 228):

This can also happen if you/someone renamed the branch.
So follow these steps (if you know that branch name is renamed)
Assuming earlier branch name as **`wrong-branch-name`** and someone renamed it to **`correct-branch-name`** So.

```
git checkout correct-branch-name
```

`git pull` (you'll see this "Your configuration specifies..")

```
git branch --unset-upstream

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/correct-branch-name
```

for older git versions `git push --set-upstream origin correct-branch-name`

`git pull` (you'll not get the earlier message )

Comment: It's not even necessary to `git push` and it won't work if the current branch is behind its remote. `git pull origin correct-branch-name` is enough.

Comment: The command to set upstream is wrong above. Do a git pull after, --unset-upstream operation, in the output of the pull you can see a error, with the command to set the upstream, like below,

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> mybranch

Comment: Worked nicely for me after removing some large files from my repo and needed to push back to a new repo i just created

Comment: For anyone visiting this more recently: '--set-upstream' is no longer supported. Now you should use "git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> main"

Comment: The only answer that worked

Comment: happened for me, that intelliJ was showing wrong branch I was on... thought I was on develop. After "git checkout develop", "git pull" passed without problems.

Comment: I had changed local branch from master to main, and when `git pull`, this error happened,   exactly as you described
your way worked nicely for me!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I second this. It was my issue with branch name being in uppercase, e.g. TASK-83, while i checked out with task-83. Surprisingly, it worked, but caused this error. Oh, git, you always surprise me ;)

Answer (score 60):

Check if your remote branch is available to pull.
I had the same issue, finally realized the remote branch was deleted by someone.

Comment: It was the same for me!

Comment: After a pull request, the merger (i.e. the person who did the merge) has the option to delete the branch that was merged into the target branch. If you try to pull at that point you'll get this error.

Comment: that is true :)

Comment: Same for me. I accidently deleted the branch...

Answer (score 32):

This is a more common error now as many projects are moving their `master` branch to another name like `main`, `primary`, `default`, `root`, `reference`, `latest`, etc, as discussed at [Github plans to replace racially insensitive terms like ‘master’ and ‘whitelist’](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2020/06/15/github-plans-to-replace-racially-insensitive-terms-like-master-and-whitelist/).

To fix it, first find out what the project is now using, which you can find via their github, gitlab or other git server.

Then do this to capture the current configuration:

```
$ git branch -vv
...
* master  968695b [origin/master] Track which contest a ballot was sampled for (#629)
...
```

Find the line describing the `master` branch, and note whether the remote repo is called `origin`, `upstream` or whatever.

Then using that information, change the branch name to the new one, e.g. if it says you're currently tracking `origin/master`, substitute `main`:

```
git branch master --set-upstream-to origin/main
```

You can also rename your own branch to avoid future confusion:

```
git branch -m main
```

Comment: thanks for catch! This main master thing is only getting more frustration.

Comment: Or `git fetch upstream`, `git checkout main`, then next time `git pull`.

Answer (score 16):

For me it was a case sensitivity issue. My local branch was Version_feature2 instead of Version_Feature2.  I re-checked out my branch using the correct casing and then git pull worked.

Comment: This turned out to be my problem too. It's not necessary obvious with fairly long/complicated branch names.

Comment: This was the issue for me as well

Comment: My case was very sensitive too!

Answer (score 11):

You can easily link your local branch with remote one by running:

```
git checkout <your-local-branch>
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<correct-remote-branch> <your-local-branch>
git pull
```

Answer (score 8):

I got a similar error when the actual cause was that my disk was full. After deleting some files, `git pull` began to work as I expected.

Comment: Same here - I guess git tries to fetch something from the remote, silently fails to write it because the disk is full, and then doesn't find the files and complains that the "ref wasn't fetched"?

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was simply lacking of initial commit on remote branch, so local branch wasn't finding anything to pull and it was giving that error message.

I did:

```
git commit -m 'first commit' // on remote branch
git pull // on local branch
```

Answer (score 6):

This error can also be received when the origin branch name has some case issue.

For example: origin branch is `team1-Team` and the local branch has been checkout as `team1-team`. Then, this `T` in `-Team` and `t` in `-team` can cause such error. This happened in my case. So, by changing the local name with the origin branch's name, the error was solved.

Answer (score 6):

I've found this error occurs frequently when pulling updates from a repo whose default `master` branch has been renamed to `main`.
Encountered this a lot after the 2020 trend of renaming `master` branch to `main` branch.

So if you had previously cloned a repo with the default `master` branch and that branch has since been renamed to `main`, one way to fix is by simply pointing your upstream from master to main:

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main master`

If that command succeeds, you should see a message like this:

> Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.

You can then rename your local branch from `master` to `main` (to keep consistent with the remote branch name) with `git branch -m master main`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with master/main branch. In my case I did not have enough free space on my harddisk. After freeing up some space, it worked.

I assume its because the files /.git needs some space to edit its file.
For example the file: 'refs/heads/feature/Sprint4/ABC-123-Branch'

Answer (score 3):

I kept running into this issue.  In my case, @Jerreck's comment about case differences in the branch names was the cause of this error.  Some Windows tools aren't aware of case sensitivity.

To turn off case-sensitivity in git, run this command:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase true
```

Note that this will impact more than branch names.  For example, if you have "Foo.h" and "foo.h" in the same directory (not a great idea when building software for Windows) then I suspect you cannot turn off case sensitivity.

Comment: This doesn't help with the issue because `core.ignorecase` option only affects your files but not git internal files (which resides in `.git` folder)

Comment: `core.ignorecase true` does not work for me (the problem was a case difference in the branch name). So I've just set upstream to the correct branch name

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i had deleted the original branch from which my current branch derived from. So in the .git/config file i had:

```
[branch "simil2.1.12"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/simil2.0.5
    rebase = false
```

the simil2.0.5 was deleted. I replaced it with the same branch name:

```
[branch "simil2.1.12"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/simil2.1.12
    rebase = false
```

and it worked

Answer (score 3):

### Check for case sensitivity

In my case, my branch name (remote) had uppercase letters, for example: `BranchName`.
Accidently, I created a branch `branchname`  (all lower case)  on my local machine and set upstream to the same, and this error appeared.

Solution:
I deleted the local repository, cloned it again, and checked out to `BranchName`

Comment: This was the case for me as well. I was working on windows (case insensitive) and my remote was a case-sensitive system. Further the remote was deleted and a new branch created with the same name, but a different capitalization.  My solution was to edit .git/config in my project root, find the relevant branch entry and correct the capitalization in the `merge =` line

Answer (score 3):

I just now experienced the problem of "no such ref was fetched", and none of the above suggestions helped. The way I solved it was to change in my local config

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

to

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I have no idea why that worked, but it did. After this change, I could pull and received what I expected.

If I change it back, I again get the "no such ref was fetched" when trying to pull. So this was definitely the fix (not flunky internet, or case differences, or full drive, or deleted remote branch, or default branch not named "master", etc).

Comment: answer to why git removed "master" https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-53050955

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here (including `git fetch --prune origin`)  worked for me after a `rebase`. Here's what did work. **Be aware that one of these commands will delete your local branch, so you'd better have it stored on your `remote origin` before running**:

- `git checkout master` // Get off the problem branch
- `git branch -d problemBranch` // Delete the problem branch
- `git pull`
- `git checkout problemBranch`
- `git push -u`
- Now `git pull` works without complaint

This resulted in no extra merges nor any problems on any other machines using the repo.

Answer (score 2):

For me this happened because i merged a branch dev into master using web interface and then tried to sync/pull using VSCode which was open on dev branch.(its weird that i could not change to master without getting this error.)

```
git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/dev'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.'
```

It makes sense that is not finding it refs/heads/dev - for me it was easier to just delete the local folder and clone again.

Comment: I understand this perfectly. The development branch existed (was first created in the origin) but at some point in time that branch got merged to master and deleted. Which is ok. But I can't stand there is no easy way to simply sync that from the origin. If the branch was merged and deleted in the origin, I don't need it locally either. Why can't git pull or git fetch simply get rid of the dangling obsolete local branch automatically?

Comment: @Simón because your local dev branch might contain changes you want to keep but not synced yet. Imagine Johnny boy over there merges his changes from his dev branch into master and per your suggestion git syncs and deletes your local dev branch...with due tomorrow, critical changes :)

Comment: Not necessarily. Git can easily tell if your local branch is ahead of the remote's. Maybe this is just a nuance that comes with adhering to GitHub's recommended workflow, for example: a branch is created on GitHub for each bug/FR/issue, a dev checkouts that branch in their local workspace (GitHub tells you how), works on code, commits, pushes, and generates a pull request; then the repo owner merges the pull request and deletes the branch. Then the dev does git pull and sees this message, and they have to manually delete the obsolete branch, a step that git could have performed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I just got exactly this error when doing "git pull" when my disk was full. Created some space and it all started working fine again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I renamed the branch on Github which in return told me to execute the following commands:

The default branch has been renamed!

```
main is now named <new_name>
```

If you have a local clone, you can update it by running:

```
git branch -m main <new_name>
git fetch origin
git branch -u origin/<new_name> <new_name>
git remote set-head origin -a
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if someone deleted the branch at remote.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same error, when I didn't use the correct case.
I could checkout out 'integration'. Git told me to perform a `git pull` to update my branch. I did that, but received the mentioned error.
The correct branch name is 'Integration' with a capital 'I'.
When I checked out that branch and pulled, it worked without problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rename the local branch

> ```
> git branch -m temp
> ```

2. Display all branches

> ```
> git branch -a
> ```

3. Check out the specific remote branch

> ```
> git checkout main
> ```

4. Delete the temp branch

> ```
> git branch -d temp
> ```

Answer (score 1):

for me, it was because when I merged develop to master, there was a config to delete the branch after a merge and that was why git pull wasn't working.

so to resolve this scenario, I had to go to the pull request and used the restore branch button to restore the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `~/.gitconfig` file in your home folder. This is where all --global settings are saved.

Or, use `git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.url` and after run `git fetch` with repository url.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue where my current branch was dev and I was checking out to MR branch and doing git pull thereafter. An easy workaround that I took was I created a new folder for MR Branch and did git pull there followed by git clone.

So basically I maintained different folders for pushing code to different branch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the master cannot be fetched in a new project.

And it worked after I put this in the command line,

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

ref: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/can-t-access-bitbucket-server-with-git-issuer-certificate-is-invalid-779171808.html

Answer (score 0):

The branch's pull request in the Github repo was approved, it was merged into the dev branch and doesn't exist on origin any more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the repo was temporary unavailable (under maintenance).

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this exact error, but none of the suggested answers (possibly the case sensitivity) was the issue. They probably are for 99% of the issues out there, but that still leaves 1%.

It turned out, mixing WSL / Linux file shares and Windows base directories was the problem. I was running WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) and has a repo that was accessed / edited from Windows, but the code was running on WSL. I may have done some git status checks from the WSL side.

The repo existed, the case was correct, the internet worked fine, none of the branches were removed, etc. Yet I also got the error *Your configuration specifies to merge with the  from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.?*

What my fix was, was to make sure all of the items were pushed / all changes recorded, then I just removed the directory and did a 'git clone' again from Windows. Then the 'git checkout' worked fine. I realize this isn't really an answer, but it did work.

I was doing Linux development where a code library automates certain operations, including 'git clone'; however, I normally do my code pushes from Windows. My guess is that the .git folder is not cross-platform compatible (not that I had any expectation it was). Yet, it usually works. Is it a bug? Debateable.

git will also occasionally try too hard to be nice and munge line endings; that's a different problem (and bordering on religion. I'm an Agnostic. Yes, there's a setting.)

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when installing packages with `yarn`. An own dependency had a renaming of branch `main` into `master`. Only updating upstream on the dependency did not fix it, I additionally had to clean the `yarn` cache.

1. Project A renamed the main branch (`main` -> `master`). Project A is a dependency of Project B.
2. `yarn install` on Project B <-- causes error
3. [Push updated upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100062/4840661) on Project A
4. `yarn install` on Project B <-- causes error
5. `yarn cache clean`
6. `yarn install` on Project B <-- works now

Answer (score 0):

Informal, but deleting my local project and recloning worked.

I was safe doing so as I had never developed a branch for merge.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the branch that was merged and deleted in the remote. Checking out to a branch that exists and then pulling helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that the rights in the GitLab repository were simply missing when cloning the repository.

Answer (score 0):

This was old question, in fact new git users still may experience the same issue

```
For example: 
 **you have repoA**
     remotes/origin/yourBranch1

 **you have repoB**
     remotes/origin/yourBranch1
     remotes/origin/yourBranch2
```

You may checkout at yourBranch1 under repoA
and thinking you are deleting remote yourBranch2 under repoB

```
then you would see below error
'Couldn't find remote ref'
```

Make sure you did checkout the branch which is under same repo,
and is not the same branch that you intended to delete

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when accidently set a url of a wrong repo. Try copying the repo URL and set it using the following command.

```
git remote set-url origin [url of your repo]
```

Answer (score -1):

If another pull just works, it means your internet wasn't connected.

Comment: A number of downvotes and yet this was the cause I had of receiving this error. I had Internet but had lost the VPN to my git server. After reconnecting to the VPN the pull worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

When i was running 'git pull' command in my root project, following error was coming:

Command:
`git pull`

Error:
**Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/main'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.**

**Soultion**:
I simply deleted **.git** folder and reinitialize .git(created .git folder again) by running `git init`  command in my root project folder and it worked.

Comment: This loses all local repo contents: unpushed branches, stash contents, tags etc.