# Preventing error Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/Feature/MyFeatureBranch' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched?

Tags: git, branch, git-pull, pull

When I do a **git pull**, I'm getting a

*Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/Feature/MyFeatureBranch'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.*

My .git/config looks like:

```
[core]
    bare = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://mycompanysgitserver

    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "0019"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/0019
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
[branch "Feature/MyFeatureBranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/Feature/MyFeatureBranch
```

If I do a **git status** I see:

On branch Feature/MyFeatureBranch
Your branch is behind 'origin/Feature/MyFeatureBranch' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

git ls-remote shows me:

```
a5389a71eea0f30dfa96cfc95f4c19bb57a5d1a6    refs/heads/feature/MyFeatureBranch
```

I've searched around including the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984371/your-configuration-specifies-to-merge-with-the-branch-name-from-the-remote-bu) and it doesn't seem that I have any of the common problems that result in this error message.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the cases of the branch names match? I'm not sure if you've hand-edited the branches here for posting publicly, but the git ls-remote output shows "feature/MyFeatureBranch" while your git config has "Feature/MyFeatureBranch" - different case for the first character.

Comment: Try a `git fetch origin MyFeatureBranch` first. What does `git remote show origin` say?

Comment: It was the case sensitivity issue.  I changed the case in my git config file.  I think I had to do another fetch with the right case.  My memory is a little fuzzy right now.

Answer (score 1):

To see a list of local and remote branches run, and confirm the remote branch exits

```
git branch --all
```

If you don't have any changes delete the local `MyFeatureBranch`, then run

```
git checkout -t origin/MyFeatureBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was as a result of the remote branch getting deleted. Incidentally, I had finished changes on my branch 'A' and merged it to 'master'. After sometime, I probably did a git fetch --prune to remove all stale references and this might have caused it. However, on the local branch, I was trying to do a git pull and obviously it failed.

Please run

> **git status**

on your current local repo and ensure you are on a valid branch. You could switch over to another branch say 'master' and do a

> **git pull**

to verify if it can pull now.