# Git submodule not getting updated - Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref '<branchname>' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

Well, this could be beaten to death question - but i am not seeing the correct answer anywhere else.  This not happening to the main module but rather to the submodule.

I have two Projects :

> c:\MainModule  and c:\Submodule. 
>  The submodule also resides at
>   c:\MainModule\submodule

I made some changes to the submodule - pushed the changes. Did a `git status`  - All good. i can see my changes in both local and remote

I then did a git pull on my main module.  Then i went to

> c:\MainModule\Submodule

folder and did a

```
git status
```

it said you branch is behind hte 'origin/<branchname> by 1 commit. do a git pull to update your local branch.

i did a `git pull` and 
thats when it says

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref '<branchname>' from
>   the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

now normally i understand this happens with the mainmodule if the remote branch is deleted. but this is weird issue happening at the submodule level - esp when i am able to see the submodule changes at that folder

i tried the following

```
git submodule update 
git submodule update --init
```

from the MainModule . i also tried various other options.

I did check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984371/your-configuration-specifies-to-merge-with-the-branch-name-from-the-remote-bu)  - but this looks to be a different reason.

I deleted the local branch and re created. i Also used other tools to update submodule  - no help

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer  - 
i had to do

```
git merge origin/<branch Name>
```

in my submodule folder and that finally fixed the issue. posting for future reference.