# Error pushing ReactJS (CRA template) code to GitHub enterprise

Tags: reactjs, git, create-react-app, github-enterprise

After cloning the empty repository I created in my *Github Enterprise* account, I created a *CRA (create-react-app) ReactJS* application. I created, committed & pushed a README.md file before generating the CRA scaffolding and it got pushed successfully. *But, after CRA app got generated,* I'm not able to push the code to the GitHub Enterprise server.

Git Bash throws the following error:

```
remote: fatal: early EOF
```

Whereas GitHub Desktop throws the following:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

I have been using GitHub enterprise for NodeJS web app dev for years now and have never faced any issue of such sort but I have not been able to push the CRA based React app scaffolding code.

I have tried referring to the following StackOverflow posts:

1. [Your configuration specifies to merge with the <branch name> from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984371/your-configuration-specifies-to-merge-with-the-branch-name-from-the-remote-bu)
2. [Git push error '[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked)
3. [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

but those didn't work. Apparently, this use case is unique as the error only gets thrown (from all my experience working with this GitHub enterprise account) when I'm pushing CRA code and no other.

Attachments (`Git Bash` & `GitHub Desktop errors`):

1. [image: Git Bash error]
2. [image: GitHub desktop error]

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36843260/1673761

> Look here: https://flyingtomoon.com/2011/04/12/git-push-is-failed-due-to-rpc-failure-result56/

> The problem is most likely because your git buffer is too low.

> You will need to increase Git’s HTTP buffer by setting the git config var “http.postBuffer” to 524288000.

```sh
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Tried this, `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` but still no luck.

Comment: Can there be any configuration at the GitHub enterprise server level which might be constraining?

Comment: can you try `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git push -u origin master`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178401/how-can-i-debug-git-git-shell-related-problems

Comment: Got the following verbose message but cannot figure any error in this. Apparently there is no error from my end: https://pastebin.com/VetEU6ZX