# How can I check whether a branch has been merged into another branch?

Tags: git

In command line, how can I check whether a branch has been merged into another branch, and if yes, find out which branch it has been merged into?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know in git if a branch has been already merged into master?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-in-git-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master)

Comment: Try `git diff master...` (and replace `master` with whatever "target" branch you want to check). If this returns `nil` then there are no changes that exist in your current branch that are not in your "target" branch. _(As always, triple check before deleting the branch and always make sure you have good backups.)_

Answer (score 18):

```
git branch --contains <branch>
```

will print all local branches where the commit labelled by `<branch>` is an ancestor.

Answer (score 5):

> With `--contains`, shows **only the branches that contain the named commit** (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are descendants of the named commit)
>
> `--contains` []
> Only list branches which contain the specified commit (HEAD if not specified)

```
git branch --contains <commit/tag/branch>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **gitg** for this. See also [visual editor](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux).