# Removing merged branches in git

Tags: bash, git

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/227026/117421

I've come up with the following is there any errors?

The idea is to find and remove old branches in git.

`git branch -r --merged origin/master` gives you all remote branches that have been merged into master. However it includes by default master itself and appears to contain HEAD -> origin/master as well.

**Find all branches merged into master excluding master and HEAD**

`git branch -r --merged origin/master | grep -v origin/master` excludes these two entries.

This is trivial to get to a loop in bash.

```
for remotebranch in $(git branch -r --merged origin/master | grep -v origin/master); do
echo $remotebranch
done
```

**However this lists the branch name including origin** which is the wrong format for `push --delete`

This can be fixed by replacing `origin/` with the empty string.

**Remove origin/ prefix**

```
for remotebranch in $(git branch -r --merged origin/master | grep -v origin/master | sed 's/origin\///g'); do
echo $remotebranch
done
```

So I think the following may be run, is it correct, or is there a better way to do it?

## Final Solution

```
for remotebranch in $(git branch -r --merged origin/master \
| grep -v origin/master \
| sed 's/origin\///g'); do
git push origin --delete $remotebranch
done
```

finally you can always run
`git fetch --prune`

Comment: Especially see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48339388/7976758

Comment: Odd choice to keep this comment but not the others.

Comment: Some "comments" were close votes, they were moved upward. Some comments were real comments, they stayed here.