# how to identify stale git branches using script

Tags: git, shell, bitbucket

I need to find and list the branches that are

- merged
- not merged
- merged but not deleted

from multiple projects and multiple repositories with single script from bit bucket and also the report should be printed in this format

```
project name: repo name: branch name: last commit date: author name:
```

I tried this in shell script

```
#!/bin/sh


  echo "Merged branches"
  for branch in `git branch -r --merged | grep -v HEAD`;
  do echo -e `git log --no-merges -n 1 --format="%ci, %cr, %an, %ae, "  $branch 
  | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r

  echo ""
  echo "Not merged branches"
  for branch in `git branch -r --no-merged | grep -v HEAD`;
  do echo -e `git log --no-merges -n 1 --format="%ci, %cr, %an, %ae, " $branch | 
  head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

by using these i can fetch only in that particular repo.
how to list all the projects and repos and execute these git commands?

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket has some well written [api documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/).
Within this documentation one can find the resource: [`/repositories`](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories)

As quoted from their documentation this endpoint:

> Returns a paginated list of all public repositories.
>   This endpoint also supports filtering and sorting of the results. See [filtering and sorting](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/filtering) for more details.

These are all **public** repositories **you** own.
Within this response there should be a git url.

You can parse the json and retrieve all git urls of every repository and store them within a variabele.
Then loop through the git repositories urls and clone each one of them by the command: `git clone --recurse-submodules GIT_URL_HERE`
The [`--recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---recurse-submodulesltpathspec) option is used here since if there are any submodules we want to get them aswell!

After all repo's are cloned succesfully go into each directory by using the [`cd DIRECTORY`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html) command.

Within these directories one can list the branches.

1. Listing all merged branches:

   1. [`git branch --merged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-in-git-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master)
   2. > lists branches merged into HEAD (i.e. tip of current branch)
2. Listing all **not** merged branches:

   1. [`git branch --no-merged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-in-git-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master)
   2. > lists branches that have not been merged

Comment: can we able to do without using api?

Comment: Yes you can, however you'll need to checkout the git repositories one by one then..

Comment: is that possible that can be done using any automation script

Comment: Yes by daily checking the api >.>" as suggested in the first place.