# Git says "already up to date" but there are no files

Tags: git

I need to merge a branch which contains a new plugin for magento to the master branch.

But if I merge the branch it says "Already up to date" but there are no files from the plugin branch nowhere.

I already checked if the path is getting ignored with `git status --ignored` but it is not.

The plugin is in **app/code/community/meanbee** but the folder does not exist.

[image]

I am confused right now...

Output of `git status --ignored`:

```
    .htaccess
    app/etc/local.xml
    dev/
    downloader/
    errors/local.xml
    media/.ftpquota
    media/catalog/
    media/css/
    media/custom/
    media/customer/
    media/dhl/
    media/downloadable/
    media/email/
    media/eternal/
    media/favicon/
    media/icons/
    media/import/
    media/messanleitungen/
    media/offline_seite/
    media/sales/
    media/tmp/
    media/videos/
    media/wysiwyg/
    media/xmlconnect/
    nbproject/
    skin/adminhtml/default/default/lib/emojione/
    var/
```

Comment: It seems like your feature branch has been already merged with the main branch. But it's unusual why you can't see the files.
Can you check if those files are present in remote repo or not?

Comment: I can't check the remote because BitBucket has a bug and I can't change branches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master Please check this link it will let you know if your feature branch is merged into master branch or not?

Comment: It says it is already merged, but the files are not there. I will now just create a new branch and copie all plugin files into my project again and commit to the new branch...