# how to list all 'active' branches in git containing unmerged commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-log

I'm struggling to make sense of the history of a couple of very large repositories that have hundreds of (old) branches which never have been deleted (even though work on most of these branches is 'done').

I'm trying to find a way to generate a list of branches that

- **contain commits after the branch was created ('not empty')**
- **have not been merged into another branch**

If my assumption is correct, this should return a list of branches that contain unmerged/active code - everything else is safe to delete.

A nice gimmick would be to to visualize this via `git log --graph` - only displaying the 'current working tree', going back only to the first commit that's present in all of the 'currently active branches'.

Any suggestions/help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: `git branch --no-merged HEAD` is probably the answer you want.  You may want to add `-r` or `-a`, or use something other than `HEAD`.  You might want to run this (adjusted) command numerous times, once for each branch name (although in that case there are some ways to do this more efficiently, at [this possible cost](https://xkcd.com/974/)).

#### Long

It's important to realize here that Git does not actually merge *branches*.  Or more precisely, we have to define what we mean by *branch* first (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)); depending on which definition we use, Git doesn't *have* branches, or does not *merge* branches, or does merge branches but then they sometimes un-merge later; or there are other possibilities depending on what *you* mean by "branch".   What Git *does* merge—the way that may be useful to your problem, that is—are *commits*.  Branch names help you and Git *find* commits, which otherwise exist on their own in a *commit graph*, and that's how you will use the answer above.

A Git *repository* is really, primarily, a collection of *commits*.  Git isn't about files—though commits do *contain* files—and is not about branches, or at least branch names (which are well-defined, unlike "branches"), though the branch names help us find the commits.  It's really just about the commits, so you need to be able to visualize commits:

> A nice gimmick would be to to visualize this via `git log --graph`

You can do just that, but:

> only displaying the 'current working tree', going back only to the first commit that's present in all of the 'currently active branches'.

The *working tree* isn't actually *in* Git, and given how poorly *branches* are defined in the first place, plus the fact that the word *active* is entirely *un*-defined, we'll probably never know what "currently active branches" even means.  So we can't possibly do that.

What *is* in Git are the commits.  The commits:

- Are numbered: each one has a unique number, or *hash ID*, represented in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  Once some hash ID is allocated to some particular commit, it means *that* commit, *forever*, in *every Git repository*.  In other words, these commit hash IDs are universally unique.<sup>1</sup>  Git gets a lot done with this principle: for instance, we hook two Git repositories up to each other, with `git fetch` or `git push`, and they exchange just the raw hash IDs and immediately know which *commits* (and hence files) the other Git needs to get.
- Are immutable: no part of any commit can ever change.  (This is true of all of Git's internal objects, all of which use the UUID hashing scheme.  The hashing only works as long as the objects cannot change.)
- Store two things: a snapshot of all files (in a special internal read-only de-duplicated format), and some metadata.  The metadata include things like who made the commit and when, but also, crucial for Git's internal workings, a list of hash IDs of *previous*, or *parent*, commits.

Usually the list of parents in each commit is just one element long, which gives us a simple linear backwards-looking chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` stores both a snapshot of all files (as of the state they had at the time someone made `H`), and some metadata.  The metadata in `H` hold the hash ID of `H`'s parent commit `G`, which stores a snapshot and some metadata; the metadata for `G` store the hash ID of `F`, which stores a snapshot and metadata; and so on, forever—or at least, until we get back to the very first commit ever, which cannot have a parent, so just doesn't:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- latest
```

We say that commit `H` points backwards to `G`, which points backwards to `F`, and so on.  Commit `A`, being the first commit, doesn't point anywhere, so that allows `git log` to stop.

To *find* `H`, though, we must tell Git its hash ID.  To avoid having to memorize hash IDs ourselves, we have *Git* save this hash ID in a name, such as a branch name, `latest`.  That name then points to `H`, which lets us get started.

---

<sup>1</sup>We can prove, via the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), that this can't actually work.  Eventually it *will* fail.  The size of the hash ID determines how soon failure becomes a distinct probability; by making it big enough, we push the failure far enough into the future that we don't care, because in Keynes' long run, we're all dead.

---

#### Now we can see how branch names work

Suppose we have a series of commits ending at `H`, plus a single branch name like `main`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

We now add a *second* name, *also pointing to `H`*, so that all the commits are now on *two branches:*

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, main
```

We need a way to pick out which *name* we're actually *using*.  To do that, we'll have Git attach the special name `HEAD` to one of the branch names:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, main (HEAD)
```

This means we're "on" `main`, having done a `git checkout main` or `git switch main`, or having started out on `main`.  Meanwhile we're *using* commit `H`.  If we'd like to use the name `dev` instead, we run:

```
git switch dev
```

and get:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

We're still using *commit* `H`, but we're using it through the *name* `dev` now.

#### A brief aside on Git's index / staging-area and your working tree

All the files in any Git commit snapshot are immutable.  But we want to be able to mutate files: we can't get any actual *new work* done if we can't *change* the files.  Git solves this problem like most version control systems: when we *check out* some commit, Git *copies the files out of the commit* into a work area.  This work area is our *working tree* or *work-tree*.

It's important to realize that these files *are not in Git*.  They came *out* of Git, but inside Git, they are in a special, read-only, compressed (sometimes highly compressed) and de-duplicated form, that only Git itself can read and literally nothing can write.  So Git *copies them out*, and the copies are not in Git.  The copies are instead ordinary everyday files, that every program can read and write in the usual way.

When programs do this, *Git does not know that they are doing this.*<sup>2</sup>  That's part of why you have to tell Git—with `git add`—that some file is updated.

Other version control systems have, historically, just *scanned for changes*.  That is, you run their equivalent of checkout and they check out some commit or file.  Then you run their equivalent of checkin / commit, and they scan everything, and you go out to lunch because this step will take at least 5 minutes and perhaps an hour or more.  Git doesn't do this: instead, Git keeps an *extra copy of every file*, but in the compressed-and-de-duplicated form.  Since these extra copies just came out of a commit, they are by definition duplicates, and therefore take no space.<sup>3</sup>  This makes up most of what Git calls its *index* or *staging area*.

When you run `git add` on some file, you're really telling Git: *Read the working tree copy, and compress it into the internal de-duplicated form.  If that turns out to be a duplicate, de-duplicate it now, so that it's prepared for the next commit.  Otherwise prepare it for the next commit now.*  Either way, *after* `git add`, the index / staging-area copy now matches the working-tree copy, and is "staged for commit".  If it matches the already-committed copy, Git doesn't *say* anything about it when you run `git status`.  If not, `git status` *says* `staged for commit`.  But in fact every file in Git's index *is* staged for commit: that's why this is the *staging area*.  If Git said `updated in proposed next commit`, that might be better, but instead Git just says `staged for commit`.

---

<sup>2</sup>For efficiency, it's sometimes nice to use an OS's file-monitoring facilities, and Git has some primitive ability to do this on some OSes.  But for the most part Git still isn't aware of this.  Git has a different efficiency trick up its sleeves (if Git can be said to have sleeves).

<sup>3</sup>These *index entries* still take space to record their names and a bunch of related data, on the rough order of about 100 bytes per file.

---

#### Making new commits

Let's say we are in this state:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

That is, we're on branch `dev` and using commit `H`.  Meanwhile we've updated some files and run `git add` on them, so that the staged-for-commit copy doesn't match the copy *in* commit `H`.  We now run `git commit`, and Git executes the following steps, in some order:

- Git collects any extra metadata it needs, such as our name and email address and the current date-and-time, and a log message.
- Git resolves the current commit to a raw hash ID (that of `H`) to put in as the list of parent commits.
- Git freezes for all time the snapshot as it appears in the index.
- Git combines all of these into a new commit, which gets a new unique hash ID; we'll call that `I`.  Note that new commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`.
- **Here's the tricky part: Git writes the new commit's hash ID into the current *branch name*.**

So now we have:

```
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

**Note that `git branch` did not create a branch; `git commit` created the branch.**  At least, that's what happened as long as "the branch" means the fact that commit `I`, now exclusively on `dev`, "branches off" from `main`.

As we make more commits, they add on to `I`:

```
          I--J   <-- dev (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

until we `git switch` back to `main`:

```
          I--J   <-- dev
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

When we *do* switch commits, Git removes, from the working tree (and its index / staging-area), the files from commit `J`, and puts in the files from commit `H` instead.  There's a bunch more trickiness here, but we'll ignore that.

If we create a third name and switch to that, and add two more commits, we get this situation:

```
          I--J   <-- dev
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

It's important to realize two things here:

1. Commits up through and including `H` are on *all branches*.
2. The name `main` is *no longer needed* in some sense: its purpose is to locate commit `H`.  It still serves this purpose, but so do commits `J` and `L`.  By starting at `dev` (`J`) and working backwards, we will reach—and hence find—commit `H`.  The same holds for commit `L`.  However, we *do* need the names `dev` and `feature` because those names are the *only* ways to find commits `I-J` and `K-L` respectively.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>If you goof this up—which is easy to do in Git—Git provides numerous ways to find the commits again, *for a while*.  Eventually those "recover from mistake" entries, called *reflogs*, will expire.  In what is probably a mistake, that has not been corrected in 15+ years, deleting a branch name deletes the branch's reflog, so one should be at least somewhat cautious about branch-name deletion.  If Git kept these reflogs, and there's work going on that might lead to this, you could "un-delete" a branch name.

---

#### True merges

Once we have a branch-y structure of commits—a commit graph with a branch in it—like this one:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

we often find it interesting and useful to use `git merge`.  What `git merge` does with these, expressed as a high-level goal, is to *combine work*.  "Work", in this case, is defined in terms of *changes*.  Git doesn't store changes: Git stores commits.  So to get *changes*, Git has to *compare commits*.

We already see this every day with `git show` or `git log -p`.  When we use these commands, Git finds a commit and uses that commit's metadata to find the commit's parent commit:

```
...--o--o--P--C--o--...
```

To "show" commit `C`, Git finds its parent `P`, extracts *both* snapshots, and compares them.  For every file that is the same, Git says nothing, and for every file that is different, Git figures out a recipe that will change the copy of that file in `P` to match the copy in `C` and produces that recipe.

If *work* is *changes*, and if we have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

then it's intuitively obvious<sup>5</sup> that if we compare the snapshot in `H` to that in `J`, we'll find out what work happened on `br1`.  If we compare the snapshot in `H` to that in `L`, we'll find out what work happened on `br2`.  Moreover, this produces two *change recipes*, as it were, that if applied to `H`, produce the snapshots in `J` and `L` respectively.  If we *combine* the two recipes, we'll *combine the work*.

That is, suppose one recipe says to modify some file, and the other doesn't mention the file at all.  The combination is to take the change.  If both recipes say to change a *shared* file, we simply combine both changes: as long as they're to different *regions* of the file, we can probably do that.  We'll skip right over the entire mechanism here and just assume that Git *can* combine changes and do so correctly.<sup>6</sup>  Git applies the combined changes to the common-starting-point snapshot, from `H`, and makes a new *merge commit* `M`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Commit `M` has a snapshot as usual: the snapshot is that built by applying the combined changes to the snapshot from `H`.  Commit `M` has metadata as usual: you are the author-and-committer, its date-and-time is "now", and its default log message is the rather useless<sup>7</sup> `merge branch br2 into br1`.  The *only* thing that is different and special about `M` is that instead of *one* parent `J`, it has two: `J` *and* `L`.  So when `git log` goes looking at what commits are "on" branch `br1`, Git will follow *both links*, and commits `L` and `K will be on the branch now, even though they were not, a moment ago.

If we don't ever need to find commits `K-L` quickly any more, we can now *delete* the name `br2`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

We can still find commit `L` by stepping back to the *second* parent of `M`, and from there we can find `K`.  So we might delete the name `br1`.  **If we don't, we get the problem you wrote the post about in the first place.**

---

<sup>5</sup>Mathematicians use this phrase to mean *I don't want to prove it, and if I put it this way, you'll be too embarrassed to ask me to do that.*

<sup>6</sup>As dumb as Git is—it has no knowledge of the *contents* of the files; it just applies simple line-by-line text rules here—this actually works surprisingly often.  But this is less true for XML or JSON data; don't let Git combine XML or other structured text without careful inspection or testing, or both.

<sup>7</sup>This is not always *completely* useless, but any auto-generated text is rarely going to be as good as something someone actually thinks about.  Most people don't normally write good merge messages, though; you can derive useful data by looking at the two parent chains.

---

#### Things that are not merges

Suppose that instead of the above branch-y diagram, we have the rather simpler:

```
          I--J   <-- dev
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Suppose we now run `git merge dev` to combine work done on `main` vs work done on `dev`.  The "work" we did on `main` will be: whatever is in commit `H` as compared to the files in commit `H`.  But the files in commit `H` will, *by definition*, match the files in commit `H`.  So there's no work done on `main` that isn't already on `main`.  To that, we want to *add* the work done on `dev`, which is what we'll see as a recipe if we diff `H` vs `J`.

Git *could* do this as a regular merge:

```
          I--J   <-- dev
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- main (HEAD)
```

but if Git did this with the standard merge code, the *snapshot* in `M` would exactly match the snapshot in `J`.  Commit `M` is in some sense not *required*.  We *do* need it if we want to know that some feature was *merged*, but we *don't* need it if we just want to keep track of the commits and all the *work*.

By default, Git *doesn't bother doing a full merge here*.  Instead, `git merge dev` just does a `git checkout` or `git switch` to commit `J`, while *dragging the branch name forward*, like this:

```
          I--J   <-- dev, main (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
```

and then there is no reason not to just draw everything on one line:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- dev, main (HEAD)
```

We can now safely delete the name `dev`, as before, leaving no trace of the merge action.  If we *don't*, though, and make more commits on `main` or otherwise advance the name `main`, we get:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- dev
               \
                K   <-- main (HEAD)
```

just as `br2` will linger behind `br1` after a true merge.

#### Now we can understand `git branch --merged` and `git branch --no-merged`

These commands needsone input: a commit.  We pick some commit, like `J` or `K` or `H` or whatever.  It then looks at all *branch names*, or with `-r`, all *remote-tracking names* (which I'll cover in a moment).  For each such name:

- the name selects some commit;
- is that commit "ahead of" or "behind" the commit we picked?

Note that can be *both*, as is the case with:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Here, commit `L`, found via name `br2`, is *behind* `br1` or commit `J` because commits `I` and `J` are only on `br1`.  But it's also *ahead of* `br1` because commits `K` and `L` are only on `br2`.  With:

```
...--o--P--C--o--...
```

commit `P` is one step behind `C` and `C` is one step ahead of `P`, and there are no complications, but when there is a "branch-y" graph structure, there are these complications.

What `--no-merged` does is look for any *names* that find any *commits* that are "ahead of" the selected commit.  So if we select commit `H`, then `git branch --no-merged` will show us both names `br1` and `br2`, as both names are ahead of `H`.  But if we select commit `J`, `git branch --no-merged` will show us only the name `br2`, because `br1` selects `J`, which is not ahead of `J`.

What `--merged` does is similar, except that it shows us any names where the name selects a commit that is *not ahead of* the one we pick.  Let's use this diagram yet again, but add the name `main` pointing to `H`, and switch to `main`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The `git branch --merged` command will, if we pick `main` / `HEAD` as the commit, show us only `main`, because `br1` and `br2` are both *ahead of* commit `H`.  Note that `--merged` counts an "even" branch as merged, and since `main` selects `H`, `git branch --merged main` prints `main`.

If we pick commit `J`, though, it will show us the names `main` and `br1`, because both of *those* names pick a commit that is not ahead of commit `J`.  Or, if we pick commit `L`, it will show us names `main` and `br2`.

#### Remote-tracking names

Git is not just a version control system.  It's a *distributed* (and actually more important here, replicated) version control system.  We make copies of repositories with `git clone`.  Each repository contains commits, but each repository *also* contains these branch names that help us *find* commits.

When we clone a repository, we copy *all of its commits*<sup>8</sup> and *none of its branch names*.  That is, the *names* in the repository we copy are *private to that particular repository*.  We can, however, *see* them while our Git, working on our repository, is hooked up to their Git software that's reading *their* repository.  So our Git takes their <name, hash-ID> pairs and stores them in *our* repository too, but first it *changes the names*.

We give their repository a name.  The standard name we use for "the" other repository (when there's only one such) is `origin`.  That is, we run:

```
git clone -o origin <url>
```

and our Git saves the URL under the name `origin`.  If we don't use `-o`, the default name is `origin` anyway, so we mostly don't use `-o`.  In any case, this name—which is almost always `origin`, though you can change it—is something Git calls a *remote*.  It's mainly a short name by which we can refer to their repository, instead of typing out the URL repeatedly.<sup>9</sup>  I like to refer to this as "their Git": their Git software answers at this URL, which connects their Git software to their repository, or "their Git".

To build the names it will use to save *their* branch names, *our* Git sticks our remote name in front of their Git's branch names: their `main` becomes our `origin/main`, for instance, and their `dev` becomes our `origin/dev`.  So after `git clone`, we have a repository with all the commits, and with all their *branch* names changed into these funny `origin`-prefixed names.  These names correspond to their branch names, but they literally are not *branch* names: if you `git checkout origin/dev` your Git tells you that it's gone into "detached HEAD" mode.

Having done all this copying, the last step of `git clone` is that our Git will *create* **one** branch name.  We pick the branch name with `-b`: `git clone -b dev url` for instance.  If we *don't* pick a name with `-b`, our Git will ask their Git what they recommend, which is usually `master` or `main`, and then our Git creates that name.

What all this means is that we end up with a repository with *all their commits* (but see footnote 8) and *one branch*.  Their branches have become our *remote-tracking names*.  Our one branch, that `git clone` created as its last step, points to the same *commit* as one of their branch names, and that's the branch we have checked out right now.

To *update* our remote-tracking names, we run `git fetch`:

```
git fetch origin
```

This tells our Git to look up the name `origin`, convert it to a URL, contact the Git software there, and have them list out their branch names and hash IDs.  Our Git can immediately tell, from the hash IDs, whether we have all of their commits, or need to get some commits from them.  If we need commits, our Git converses with their Git to make a more complete list, then gets their new commits and stuffs those into our repository: because these are the *same* commits, they have the *same hash IDs*.  Now we have all their commits, plus any commits we had before that they didn't have.

Having obtained from them any new commits they have that we need, our Git now updates our remote-tracking names to remember which commits their *branch* names remember.  And then we're done fetching and our Git disconnects from their Git.

(If we want to *send* them commits that *we* have that *they* don't, we use `git push`.  This is almost a mirror image of `git fetch`, with one really huge exception: they don't have any remote-tracking names for *us*.  We ask them to create or set one of their *branch* names, after we send them new commits.  But we'll skip over all of this here.)

---

<sup>8</sup>This is a bit of an overstatement: we copy the *reachable* commits, and we can deliberately limit how many of those we copy too.  But the *default* is to copy all reachable commits, and people generally don't worry about nominally-removed, still-findable-by-reflog commits, so saying "all commits" is a good way to think of it, as long as you remember that there's a footnote.

<sup>9</sup>In primeval Git, you really did have to type out the URL each time.  This was pretty error-prone and the Git folks invented a bunch of different hacks to get around it.  The one that really stuck, in the end, was this idea of a *remote*, `origin`.

---

#### Conclusion

The `git branch` command is the user-facing (or *porcelain*) command that iterates over branch names, or things that look like branch names such as remote-tracking names.  It also lets us create and delete branch names, though that's not what we're concerned with here.

Using `--merged` or `--no-merged`, we can pick out *one commit* in our repository, and ask which names—branch and/or remote-tracking names—in our repository point to specific commits that are either *not ahead of* (`--merged`) or *are* ahead of (`--no-merged`) the one commit we picked out.  Because of the nature of the commit graph and the way branch names work, that usually gets us what we want here.

(Note that a so-called *squash merge*, which we did not cover above, is not a merge at all, so this does not work if someone has been using squash merge.)

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer! ... forgive me to stick with my original nomenclature here:

If I get it correctly, calling `git branch --merged` on each and every of the branches will tell me what other branches are 'part of' the current branch/HEAD and therefore are integrated / thus can be deleted safely (ofc some additional checks i.e. not deleting main/dev/etc will be required).

Comment: I think what you're saying matches up with reality, yes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [toreks amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70676402/2279385) I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538778/2279385) - figuring out 'obsolete' branches really breaks down to

```
git branch -r | xargs -t -n 1 git branch -r --contains
```

I came up with a PowerShell snippet that incorporates `git branch --merged` that could be integrated into a posh-based environment:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  # path to local git repository
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]
  $Path,

  # the branches (regex) in this list will be ignored
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
  [string[]]
  $IgnoreBranches = @('main', 'master', 'dev', 'develop', '^.+_Maintenance$')
)
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

function Exec {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [scriptblock]
    $ScriptBlock
  )
  $LASTEXITCODE = 0
  try {
    & $ScriptBlock
    $theEc = $LASTEXITCODE
  }
  finally {
    if ($theEc -ne 0) {
      Write-Error "expected 0 exit code, got $theEc"
      Write-Error $ScriptBlock.ToString()
      throw "command exited with $theEc"
    }
  }
}

Push-Location $Path
try {

  # ensure we're not analyzing a shallow checkout, prune branches deleted on remote
  Exec { git fetch --prune }

  # get list of all branches that exist on remote
  $remoteBranches = (Exec { git branch -r }).Trim()

  # map used to store wich branches are fully contained in other branches (b -> fully contained in (a,c,d))
  # string -> string[]
  $fullyContainedBranches = @{}

  # foreach branch, figure out what other branches are "fully contained" -> candidates for deletion
  foreach ($b in $remoteBranches) {
    $b = $b.Split(' ')[0]
    Write-Verbose " checking fully integrated branches of '$b'"
    $fullyContained = Exec { git branch -r --merged $b }
    
    if (-not $fullyContained) {
      Write-Verbose "  '$b' is already gone for good!"
      $fullyContainedBranches[$b] = @()
      continue
    }

    foreach ($f in $fullyContained) {
      $f = $f.Replace('* ', '').Trim()
      Write-Verbose "   -> '$f' is in '$b'"
        
      if ($f -eq $b) {
        continue
      }

      if (-not $fullyContainedBranches[$f]) {
        $fullyContainedBranches[$f] = @()
      }

      $fullyContainedBranches[$f] += $b
    }
  }

  
  $fullyContainedBranches.Keys | Foreach-Object {
    $branchName = $_

    if ($IgnoreBranches) {
      if (($IgnoreBranches | ForEach-Object { $branchName -match $_ }) -contains $true) {
        Write-Verbose "ignoring $branchName"
        return
      }
    }
    # put output objects to pipeline
    @{
      branch       = $branchName
      contained_in = $fullyContainedBranches[$branchName]
    }
  }
}
finally {
  Pop-Location
}
```